# How to add a hierarchical tag in an XML file though XSL?

Tags: xml

I am facing a problem in XML transformation. The XML tag hierarchy is as follows:

```
<Pick_Slips_Detail_Lines_S3>
<Header_Custom_Section_S15>
//This tag contains the header data (Example:Pick Slip Number)
</Header_Custom_Section_S15>
Then the Detail lines are printed.
</Pick_Slips_Detail_Lines_S3>

<Pick_Slips_Detail_Lines_S3>
The detail lines are printed. This detail line belongs to the previous Pick Slip Number.
</Pick_Slips_Detail_Lines_S3>

<Pick_Slips_Detail_Lines_S3>
The detail lines are printed. This detail line belongs to the previous Pick Slip Number.
</Pick_Slips_Detail_Lines_S3>

My requirement is to:
<PickSlipList>
<Pick_Slips_Detail_Lines_S3>
<Header_Custom_Section_S15>
//This tag contains the header data (Example:Pick Slip Number)
</Header_Custom_Section_S15>
Then the Detail lines are printed.
</Pick_Slips_Detail_Lines_S3>

<Pick_Slips_Detail_Lines_S3>
The detail lines are printed. This detail line belongs to the previous Pick Slip Number.
</Pick_Slips_Detail_Lines_S3>

<Pick_Slips_Detail_Lines_S3>
The detail lines are printed. This detail line belongs to the previous Pick Slip Number.
</Pick_Slips_Detail_Lines_S3>
</PickSlipList>
```

My requirement is to print the Pick Slip Number at every page on the header. Since there is no parent tag for `<Pick_Slips_Detail_Lines_S3>` and `<Header_Custom_Section_S15>`, I face the problem while printing.

I am trying to search something in XML transformation. But I don't know how to transform the XML tag hierarchy.

Comment: Your formatting seems a bit broken here, perhaps you could review it to make your question easier to read.

Answer (score -1):

The formatted XML is:
   
-  
- 
- 
  LGT00003 
  Print Pick Slips 
  grpsgh11 
  grpsgh11 
  JPY811B 
  NPANDIT 
  *ALL 
  Lafarge 
  E811 
  12/04/10 
  13:30:38 
  
- 
- 
  1 
  Date - 
  2010-04-12 
  Lafarge 
  R42520 
  13:30:39 
  Time - 
  P I C K S L I P 
  Page - 
  1 
  REPRINT 
  
- 
  2 
  Date - 
  2010-04-12 
  Lafarge 
  R42520 
  13:30:39 
  Time - 
  P I C K S L I P 
  Page - 
  1 
  REPRINT 
  
- 
  3 
  Date - 
  2010-04-12 
  Lafarge 
  R42520 
  13:30:39 
  Time - 
  P I C K S L I P 
  Page - 
  1 
  REPRINT 
  
- 
  4 
  Date - 
  2010-04-12 
  Lafarge 
  R42520 
  13:30:39 
  Time - 
  P I C K S L I P 
  Page - 
  1 
  REPRINT 
  
  
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
   
- 
- 
  1 
  760 
  Pick Slip # 
  Customer No 
  100809 
  Ship To 
  100810 
  SO 
  05_LOY_DO_C_D 
  00010 
  Ship To: 
  Sold To: 
  05_LOY_DO_C_D 
  Order Number 
  10000304 
  1 
  Related P.O. 
  Hasti Co-Op. Indl. Estate 
  JONES INDUSTRIAL ESTATE 
  GB20100 
  Vyarwali Road , Ting-Tong Avenue 
  Brn/Plt 
  RHYL CH3 1QM 
  Scenic Plaza , Stardom Complex 
  United Kingdom 
  RMA Number 
  Old Baazaar , England 
  RHYL CH3 1QM 
  00010 
  United Kingdom 
  GBP 
  Attention: 
  Attention: 
- 
  1 
  Type the Pick slip here 
  
   
- 
  1 
  Order Date 
  Driver Must have Photo ID 
  Promised 
  Ship 
  Customer P.O. 
  F.O.B. 
  gdsh 
  2010-04-12 
  Inst 
  2010-04-12 
  Pick Date/ 
  Description 
  Item No. / Cust. Item No. 
  Location / Lot 
  Time 
  Extended Amount 
  Line 
  <__Revision_ID22>/ Revision 
  Shipped 
  Backordered 
  UOM 
  Price 
  
  
  12.5 x 1200 x2400 SE Standard 
  .. 
  100810 
  72641 
  1.000 
  1.0000 
  SH 
  0 
  2010-04-12 
  8.5000 
  8.50 
  GB20100 
  2.8800 
  M2 
  Dual UOM 
  Dual Shipped 
  0 
  SO 
  0.0000 
  Per 
  0.00 
  .00 
  Related Order Number 
  Board 
  Shipment Number 
  13603 
  Ship To Contact 
  Ship To Attention 
  Y 
  72641 
  1 
  1 
  1 
  1 
  N 
  100810 
  GB20100 
  Y 
  Y 
  0 
  .0240 
  00010 
  10000304 
  Original Order Number/Type 
  Original Invoice Number/Type 
  Reason Code 
  
- 
  1 
  12.5 x 1200 x2400 SE Standard 
  100810 
  72801 
  2.000 
  2.0000 
  SH 
  0 
  2010-04-12 
  8.5000 
  17.00 
  GB20100 
  .0778 
  M2 
  Dual UOM 
  Dual Shipped 
  0 
  SO 
  0.0000 
  Per 
  0.00 
  .00 
  Related Order Number 
  Board 
  Shipment Number 
  13603 
  Ship To Contact 
  Ship To Attention 
  Y 
  72801 
  1 
  1 
  1 
  1 
  N 
  100810 
  GB20100 
  Y 
  Y 
  0 
  .0480 
  00010 
  10000304 
  Original Order Number/Type 
  Original Invoice Number/Type 
  Reason Code 
  
- 
  1 
  12.5 x 1200 x2400 SE Standard 
  100810 
  72801 
  3.000 
  3.0000 
  PL 
  0 
  2010-04-12 
  8.5000 
  1836.00 
  GB20100 
  8.4000 
  M2 
  Dual UOM 
  Dual Shipped 
  0 
  SO 
  0.0000 
  Per 
  0.00 
  .00 
  Related Order Number 
  Board 
  Shipment Number 
  13603 
  Ship To Contact 
  Ship To Attention 
  Y 
  72801 
  1 
  1 
  1 
  1 
  N 
  100810 
  GB20100 
  Y 
  Y 
  0 
  5.1840 
  00010 
  10000304 
  Original Order Number/Type 
  Original Invoice Number/Type 
  Reason Code 
  
- 
- 
  1 
  Driver Signature 
  Customer Signature 
  Shippable Weight 
  Total Order 
  Sales Tax 
  <__Final___ID4>**Final** 
  1861.50 
  Tax Rt 
  
   
- 
  2 
  761 
  Pick Slip # 
  Customer No 
  100809 
  Ship To 
  100810 
  SO 
  05_LOY_DO_C_D 
  00010 
  Ship To: 
  Sold To: 
  05_LOY_DO_C_D 
  Order Number 
  10000305 
  1 
  Related P.O. 
  Hasti Co-Op. Indl. Estate 
  JONES INDUSTRIAL ESTATE 
  GB20100 
  Vyarwali Road , Ting-Tong Avenue 
  Brn/Plt 
  RHYL CH3 1QM 
  Scenic Plaza , Stardom Complex 
  United Kingdom 
  RMA Number 
  Old Baazaar , England 
  RHYL CH3 1QM 
  00010 
  United Kingdom 
  GBP 
  Attention: 
  Attention: 
- 
  2 
  Type the Pick slip here 
  
   
- 
  2 
  Order Date 
  Driver Must have Photo ID 
  Promised 
  Ship 
  Customer P.O. 
  F.O.B. 
  23525 
  2010-04-12 
  Inst 
  2010-04-12 
  Pick Date/ 
  Description 
  Item No. / Cust. Item No. 
  Location / Lot 
  Time 
  Extended Amount 
  Line 
  <__Revision_ID22>/ Revision 
  Shipped 
  Backordered 
  UOM 
  Price 
  
  
  12.5 x 1200 x2400 SE Standard 
  .. 
  100810 
  72641 
  1.000 
  1.0000 
  PL 
  0 
  2010-04-12 
  8.5000 
  612.00 
  GB20100 
  207.3600 
  M2 
  Dual UOM 
  Dual Shipped 
  0 
  SO 
  0.0000 
  Per 
  0.00 
  .00 
  Related Order Number 
  Board 
  Shipment Number 
  13604 
  Ship To Contact 
  Ship To Attention 
  Y 
  72641 
  1 
  1 
  1 
  1 
  N 
  100810 
  GB20100 
  Y 
  Y 
  0 
  1.7280 
  00010 
  10000305 
  Original Order Number/Type 
  Original Invoice Number/Type 
  Reason Code 
  
- 
  2 
  12.5 x 1200 x2400 SE Standard 
  100810 
  72801 
  2.000 
  2.0000 
  SH 
  0 
  2010-04-12 
  8.5000 
  17.00 
  GB20100 
  .0778 
  M2 
  Dual UOM 
  Dual Shipped 
  0 
  SO 
  0.0000 
  Per 
  0.00 
  .00 
  Related Order Number 
  Board 
  Shipment Number 
  13604 
  Ship To Contact 
  Ship To Attention 
  Y 
  72801 
  1 
  1 
  1 
  1 
  N 
  100810 
  GB20100 
  Y 
  Y 
  0 
  .0480 
  00010 
  10000305 
  Original Order Number/Type 
  Original Invoice Number/Type 
  Reason Code 
  
- 
  2 
  Firecheck Board 
  STD 
  100810 
  72803 
  3.000 
  3.0000 
  SH 
  0 
  2010-04-12 
  9.7100 
  29.13 
  GB20100 
  .1100 
  M2 
  Dual UOM 
  Dual Shipped 
  0 
  SO 
  0.0000 
  Per 
  0.00 
  .00 
  Related Order Number 
  Shipment Number 
  13604 
  Ship To Contact 
  Ship To Attention 
  Y 
  72803 
  1 
  1 
  1 
  1 
  N 
  100810 
  GB20100 
  Y 
  Y 
  0 
  .0960 
  00010 
  10000305 
  Original Order Number/Type 
  Ori

Comment: Edit your question and format the data — don't post unformatted data as an "answer"!